# What happened to `Solution.LoadStandAloneProject` in Roslyn's new version (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis)?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Today Microsoft open-sourced a new version of Roslyn and since this release is the first one in about a year and a half, there are an unsurprisingly large number of migration issues.  (`Symbol` -> `ISymbol`, and basically every non-interface to an interface are predominant)  However, I used to use:

```
Solution.LoadStandAloneProject(projectFile);
```

To obtain a solution that was created from a `.csproj` file.  (there were also static methods that consumed a `.sln` file in the same way)

However, the new version, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` does not have a `Solution` class that contains any static methods.  What is the correct method to call in the new API to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 10):

[Kirill Osenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37899/kirill-osenkov) [provided](https://twitter.com/KirillOsenkov/status/451908853412544512) the answer:

```
MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenSolutionAsync()
```

(I asked this question in all sincerity, but then Kirill provided this answer. Marking as CW since I'm just quoting him, but figured this might be useful to future visitors)